# Badges are not working with dynamic values in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Storing cart items in $rootScope.cart = [] arrays. I put badge on cart tab like this

```
<ion-tab title="Cart" badge="$rootScope.cart.length" badge-style="badge-assertive" icon="ion-ios-cart" ui-sref="app.tab.cart" id="tabsController-tab2">
```

I is currently not working.

If I put badge="3" then its working.
some help on how to put a dynamic value in badge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `$rootScope`

FROM

```
badge="$rootScope.cart.length"
```

TO

`badge="cart.length`"

You would use this the same way as you use `$scope.`

Ensure that `$rootScope.cart` was initialized and populated correctly in the Controller.

```
$rootScope.cart = [];
$rootScope.cart.push(1); //etc
$rootScope.cart.push(2);
$rootScope.cart.push(3);
```